# When to use rabbitmq vHost over separate queue

Tags: rabbitmq, vhosts

#### TL;DR

one queue per message type or one vhost per message type? When to use vHost over separate queue?

#### Details

Currently, we only have one single queue and several consumers to consume all messages. Those messages have a `type` property to differentiate from each other. It was well for a long time. But recently, we find some type (say, `Type A`) of messages are much more than others, which cause other kinds of message get consumed until a bunch of the `Type A` messages are consumed.

So we want to separate those messages by their type. The first idea come to me is to create queues for each kind of message. And, then I notice that I can also make use of the vhost for each kind of message.

Is vhost overkill for above scenario? When to use vhost over separate queues?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosts provide logical grouping and separation of resources.

RabbitMQ is multi-tenant system, so usually vhost should be used if you want a complete logical separation(resource control, authentication,etc) of Type A message.

In my case we shared RabbitMQ with multiple teams(tenants) each team had its own vhost.

For your case, I think queue should be good solution if you don't want to have a logical separation like different server.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you should use multiple virtual hosts in a server depends on your specific needs. If you have multiple applications or users that need to be isolated from each other, then using multiple virtual hosts is a good way to do that. It also allows you to control access to resources on a per-virtual host basis.

However, using multiple virtual hosts can also add some overhead to your server. So, if you don't need the isolation or control that multiple virtual hosts provide, then you may not want to use them.

Here are some things to consider when deciding whether or not to use multiple virtual hosts:

- The number of applications or users that you have
- The level of isolation that you need
- The amount of overhead that you can afford

If you're not sure whether or not to use multiple virtual hosts, you can always ask for advice from a more experienced administrator.